# Adding an iframe at runtime to the page refreshes the page

Tags: html, blazor

I have a program using RadzenHtmlEditor that, when I add an iframe with *src* to an HTML page in the editor, the page that the editor resides in, refreshes. The iframe that I add in the HTML editor is:

```
$"<iframe width='{imageWidth}px' height='{imageHeight}px' frameborder='0' scrolling='yes' src='{urlExcel}' {style}></iframe>"
```

If I am *quick* enough and save the iframe in the editor, as soon as the iframe is dropped, the HTML file inside the iframe is then saved in the editor, but if I am slow the new content (iframe) is lost after a page refresh. How to stop a page refresh when I add the iframe on the page?

Main page:

```
<RadzenHtmlEditor 
        @bind-Value="@CurrentPageContent" 
        Disabled="@editorDisabled" 
        Style="height: 77vh;" 
        Execute=@OnExecute>

    <RadzenHtmlEditorUndo />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorRedo />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorSeparator />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorBold />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorItalic />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorUnderline />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorStrikeThrough />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorSeparator />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorColor />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorBackground />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorRemoveFormat />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorAlignRight />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorAlignCenter />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorAlignLeft />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorJustify />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorBackground />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorFontName />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorFontSize />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorFormatBlock />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorIndent />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorOrderedList />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorUnorderedList />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorLink />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorUnlink />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorImage />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorSubscript />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorSuperscript />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorRemoveFormat />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorCustomTool CommandName="InsertImage" Icon="image" />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorCustomTool CommandName="InsertAudio" Icon="audio_file" />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorCustomTool CommandName="InsertVideo" Icon="video_file" />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorCustomTool CommandName="InsertExcel" Icon="table_view" />
    <RadzenHtmlEditorCustomTool CommandName="InsertPDF" Icon="picture_as_pdf" />
</RadzenHtmlEditor>
```

Popup page component:

```
<LayoutView Layout="typeof(DialogLayout)">
    <ChildContent>
        <div>
            
            <BlazorInputFile.InputFile OnChange="@(args => OnChange2(args))" class="form-control" accept="@((BookFileType == BookFileType.Audio ? "audio/*" : (BookFileType == BookFileType.Video ? "video/*" : (BookFileType == BookFileType.Image ? "image/*" : (BookFileType == BookFileType.Excel ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" : "application/pdf")))))">

            </BlazorInputFile.InputFile>            
            <RadzenProgressBar Value="@percentComplete" Max="100" ShowValue="true" Mode="ProgressBarMode.Determinate">
            </RadzenProgressBar>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 mb-2">
            <label>Media Width:</label>&nbsp;
            <RadzenNumeric Placeholder="Media Width" TValue="int" @bind-Value="imageWidth"
                           Disabled="@(BookFileType == BookFileType.Audio)">

            </RadzenNumeric>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Media Height:</label>&nbsp;
            <RadzenNumeric Placeholder="Media Height" TValue="int" @bind-Value="imageHeight"
                           Disabled="@(BookFileType == BookFileType.Audio || BookFileType == BookFileType.Video || BookFileType == BookFileType.Image)">

            </RadzenNumeric>
        </div>
    </ChildContent>
</LayoutView>
```

I insert an iframe HTML from the "InsertExcel" command.

Comment: show the razor markup for the page please

Comment: How is the popup related to this? Where is the code for `InsertExcel`? What is the relationship between these things? You have chosen to show partial segments of the page/components - why? I suspect you are experiencing a Blazor automatic re-render of something that has been modified by JavaScript - but with only partial visibility of the problem I have no way to be sure.

Comment: The problem gone away when I replaced RadzenFileInput with BlazorInputFile.InputFile with almost the same code inside OnChange previously I used RadzenFileInput. the above code has BlazorInputFile.InputFile instead. I was in the middle of writing the new way. so I copied and pasted the new component markup.